# Clearing Footer not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clear the footer like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="footer clear">Footer</div>
<div>
```

---

```
.left {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}

.footer {
      background-color: orange;
}

// clear
.clear {
   clear: both;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RYYFw/8/

But the footer is not clearing. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Indeed, remove the invalid comment > http://jsfiddle.net/RYYFw/15/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's your comment `//` causing the error. It is not allowed in CSS.

Use `/* comment */`

Comment: To expand on this answer, the `// clear` comment you have on line 15 is throwing an `end-of-stylesheet` exception, preventing any further styling from being rendered.

Comment: nice catch buddy. I was going to upvote the question for some research effort :P

Comment: @Mr_Green i saw someone else had the exact same thing couple of hours ago. it is so confusing where html, js and css have all different commenting rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the invalid `//` comment you'll get your desired result..